# MySQL join two tables based on a time field returning the largest previous time

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables like so:

```
EventTable (EID, Name, EventTime)
VideoTable (VID, StartTime, Video, DurationSecs)
```

The EventTable contains events that occur at a particular time.
The VideoTable contains a list of video files and their starting times.

What I would like to return is a list of all events and the correct video file (and hopefully time into the video file) for each event.

Consider the following data:

```
EventTable
1, EV1, 2010-01-01 12:00:00
2, EV2, 2010-01-01 12:15:00
3, EV3, 2010-01-01 12:30:00

VideoTable
1, 2010-01-01 11:30:00, A.mpg, 2700
2, 2010-01-01 12:15:00, B.mpg, 2700
3, 2010-01-01 13:00:00, C.mpg, 1800
```

The return list would be as follows:

```
EV1, A.mpg, 1800 (secs)
EV2, B.mpg, 0 (secs)
EV3, B.mpg, 900 (secs)
```

How could i acheive this?

***EDIT***

The Time columns are DATETIME types. There is no relationship between EID and VID. The duration column specifies the video duration in seconds.

Comment: What have you tried?  And what are the data types of the start and event time columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  e.Name,
  v.Video,
  TO_SECONDS(v.StartTime) - TO_SECONDS(e.EventTime) AS SecsIntoVideo
FROM EventTable e
  LEFT JOIN VideoTable v
    ON e.EventTime BETWEEN v.StartTime AND v.starttime + INTERVAL (v.DurationSecs)
```

Comment: For anyone reading this TO_SECONDS appears new to MySQL 5.5. The previous functions is TIME_TO_SEC()

Comment: @Simon: Thanks, didn't know about that, will keep in mind from now on.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the event and start time columns are DATETIME (DATE would work too, but you have time declared in the example):

```
SELECT e.name, v.video,
       ABS(TO_SECONDS(v.starttime) - TO_SECONDS(e.eventtime))
  FROM EVENT e
  JOIN VIDEO v ON v.vid = e.eid
```

#### Reference

- [TO_SECONDS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_to-seconds)

Answer (score 1):

This would be super simple if you had 2 time columns in the VideoTable (for start and end). That's how time problems like this are usually done (cf. Snodgrass, Celko). Then you do something like:

```
SELECT e.name, v.vido, DATEDIFF(v.starttime, e.eventtime)
  FROM Event e, Video v
 WHERE e.eventtime BETWEEN v.startTime AND v.endTime
```

Barring that, you would have to do some other machinations. Adding the end times would be pretty easy.